# Upload certificate to IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-iam

I've developed a django application and successfully deployed it to AWS Beanstalk.
Now I would like to SSL certify and I have successfully created a certificate by following the documentation here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl.html

But I am wondering, what's next? I have successfully run the last line

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out example.com.pfx -inkey privatekey.pem -in server.crt
```

But then I don't know what I can do next? This guide doesn't quite show me what's the next step.

Comment: I don't even know where the exported pfx file "example.com.pfx" is exported. The guide from AWS was just so confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Upload the certificate by running the following command:**

```
$ aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name ExampleCertificate --certificate-body file://Certificate.pem --certificate-chain file://CertificateChain.pem --private-key file://PrivateKey.pem
```

Note: Replace the file names and ExampleCertificate with the names for your uploaded files and certificate. For more information, see upload-server-certificate.

After the certificate is uploaded, the command returns metadata about the uploaded certificate, including the certificate's Amazon Resource Name (ARN), friendly name, identifier (ID), and expiration date. You can view the uploaded certificate by running the following command:

```
$ aws iam list-server-certificates
```

More docs [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/import-ssl-certificate-to-iam/)

Comment: You can run it from any terminal session that has valid AWS credentials for your account.

Comment: thanks @MC_, I think that's correct. However, when I input that, I've got this error: `User not authorized to perform IAM:uploadservercertificate ` . Have you bumped into this error before?

Comment: Add that permission to the policy that you have attached to your user.

Comment: I have this but still doesn't work:
`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Hey MC_, I figured out that I can upload the certificate via AWS ACM :) thanks!